# Math and geometry software to create instructional videos

Tags: math-software

I am looking into starting an amateur project for online tutoring. I need a math/geometry program that I can use to create shapes, graph functions, and create animation. I know of many types of software (such as geogebra) but they have restrictions for commercial use. In other words, I can't use the material or features (even screenshots) to gain a profit. Does anyone know of any programs/ software that I can use for my project?

Note: I don't mind software or programs that I can purchase for a one time fee.

Comment: I don't understand the 'amateur project' and 'to gain a profit'? Which is it? One is a reasonable question here, the other is a shopping suggestion which is not.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if an amateur project could make a profit...

Comment: Then it is a professional endeavour. And people get paid consulting fees.

Comment: I think you missed my sarcasm. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Your intended sarcasm is hardly concomitant with the wording of the question...

Comment: [JSXGraph](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/) is one option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Contact the geogebra support people; there may be some provision to pay a fee for the right to distribute-for-profit screenshots or animations produced.

2) See if Mathematica meets your needs -- but this is not a cheap solution, the commercial cost is about $2500. However, Mathematica is a truly professional, well-made tool and the time it saves you might be worth the cost.

PS- Don't be biased by lack of features in Wolfram Alpha:  That is emphatically *not* like the full-blown Mathematica.

Comment: I guess I am trying to avoid the large cost. I have already contacted Geogebra. Just waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 14):

You can take a look at [**GNU Dr. Geo**](http://drgeo.eu) a free software of mine, there is no commercial limitation and you can even redistribute it along your work.

You can do classic interactive geometry with:
[image: Mouse and clic construction]

Or you can use its programming features to design very original sketches:
[image: Programmed chaotic sequence]

More over, it is very easy to modify Dr. Geo from itself, in case of need!

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to mention that you are the creator of Dr. Geo.

Comment: Right, fixed...

Comment: So my answer is downvoted because.... I am the author of this free software? Nevertheless, I think I answer appropriately the question, I take time to illustrate it with related examples and I do not hide myself behind anonymous pseudo.